# Customer Import including MD5 hashed password

Tags: magento-1.9, php, password

I imported all my clients from my old Magento, however I could not get the password, I saw in some places that I should get the password hash that would be the password cryptographed with the salt, I do not want to know the password of the user, I simply want to keep the password how could I do this? I'm importing from Magento 1.4 to Magento 1.9

**How do I get**

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app(0);

        $id = 64995;
        $usuario_loaded = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
        $name = $usuario_loaded->getName();
        $hash = $usuario_loaded->getPasswordHash();

        print_r($name.' '.$hash);

        RESULT: Gustavo Souza f125f7e9cad50ea2dabf77673d555771a0230e218a6890e048b0a895ce532507:cM7m7Ay6x40UEGNX5t5aq8xFRJacXQne
```

**How do I insert**

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app(0);

        $id = 64995;
        $hash = 'f125f7e9cad50ea2dabf77673d555771a0230e218a6890e048b0a895ce532507:cM7m7Ay6x40UEGNX5t5aq8xFRJacXQne';
        $usuario_loaded = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
        $name = $usuario_loaded->getName();
        $usuario_loaded->setPasswordHash($hash);
        $usuario_loaded->save();
```

This would be my user, in the old magento I soon with the same password, but in the new magento I try to use the same password and I can not. Would it have something with the old encryption key of the other magento?

Comment: Did you try this ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162442/how-to-import-md5-password-to-magento-2